# How to communicate between two Go Programs?

Tags: go

[Program which I am trying to make like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kokTN.png)

There are three GO Porgram, they are Go program 1, Go Program 2 , Go Program 3

Go Program 1 
Which get data from serial port and sent to Go Program 2

GO Program 2
Recv. the data from Go program 1 and sent it to MQTT

GO Program 3
It should be web framework as I need Web UI to control and manage these GO program 1 & Go Program 2

The Go Program 3 task are:

- To start stop the GO Program 1 & 2
- To change or set the COM port of Go Program 1 and publish topics
- To change the broker address ,username & Password of Go Program 2

How to make communicate or Pipes between all the the three GO Programs.

Comment: Of course it's possible to set up communication between two Go programs. There are many ways to do this. What have you tried? Show your code. What problems have you encountered?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Flimzy I have done this in python with flask, now i am trying to do the same concept in Go

Comment: @Arvindh: That's good, so you know the basic principles. But you still haven't answered the essential question: What have you tried? Include your code.

Comment: @Flimzy I don't know to how to start this concept in GOLANG, In Python i have used pipes for process communication, but in golang i am not understanding how to use channels to communicate with another running go program.

Comment: If you don't know how to start programming in Go, [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) is your best starting point.

Comment: But you cannot use channels to communicate with other programs. Channels are for communication between functions or goroutines within the same program.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes I have gone through all the topics in  https://gobyexample.com/.

Comment: Great. Then you should be ready to write your first Go program, and show us your code here, along with an explanation of any problems you're facing.

Comment: @Flimzy Is there any efficient way to communicate with another running Go program . Or i need to change my concept in GOLANG

Comment: There are many ways--the same exact ways that are available to Python or any other language: The network, Unix pipes, shared memory, semaphores, signals, etc.

Comment: @Flimzy I am not yet start develop in GOLANG. As i am not have clarity in communication between Two different GO programs.

Comment: `net.Listen` and `net.Dial` may help you should take a look. https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/13#section7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the discussion in comments I think you make an assumption that Go has some special way for IPC that Python doesn't; that's not exactly true. Channels are useful for communication *within a single process*. If you want these programs to be truly separate (processes) you'll need all the usual IPC - you can use pipes, or sockets, or shared memory, or what have you.

Personally I'd recommend using sockets, because Go is really well suited for network programming and writing socket servers and clients. Also, once your application uses sockets it's much easier to port these different processes to run on multiple machines, across the internet, etc. In addition you can then leverage higher-level protocol levels and use things like RPCs.

---

To create a socket server, use `net.Listen`, and call `Accept` in a loop on the returned object. Each connection returned by `Accept` is a remote client you can communicate with - I'd recommend a goroutine here if you want concurrency between multiple clients.

For a first cut in a project like yours, however, I'd go for the `net/rpc` package which is very simple to use and gives a much higher level API to sending remote commands to other processes.